# GoRouter module oriented

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-go-router

I'm studying some new packages and I got to know the go router, but I would like to use it in a simpler way, that is, guided by modules according to the structure of the project and source code:

https://github.com/jameshuntt3/example_package_app

Here is the source code above, so I would like to know if anyone has experienced this, or knows how to resolve the error, as it gives an error when redirecting to the route I specified, sometimes even closing the application, and i'm adopting this approach because I've used modules, mobx, getx, provider and this form of routing for me is more efficient since each module has its own routes

I've already tried to add the navigatorKey within the ShellRoute both in the parents and in the children but it still didn't work as it should.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.